# jquery ajax get success

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can somebody tell me how to ensure the below code only returns success when `msg` is not null.

Occasionally it fires the `success` function even when `msg.Text` is undefined.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: params,
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.Text != undefined) {
            $('#mediumText').val(msg.Text).blur();
        } else {
            console.log("failed to load");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: check if (msg != null)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the response:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: params,
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.Text != undefined) {
            if (msg.Text.Length > 0) {
                $('#mediumText').val(msg.Text).blur();
            } else {
                console.log("failed to load");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            console.log("failed to load");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the length and its empty ot not.

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
url: url,
type: "GET",
data: params,
success: function (msg) 
{
      if (msg.Text != null && msg.Text.Length > 0) 
      {
           $('#mediumText').val(msg.Text).blur();
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("failed to load");
          return false;
      }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just check for a [falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/)
value:

```
  if (msg.Text) {
     ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If msg.Text is undefined that does not mean the call was unsuccessful, so it is completely OK to call success function. You must check msg.Text inside success callback.

Comment: Many thanks for all the responses. I have now fixed the issue.

I was using a bootstrap button with an icon inside. The problem occurred when the user clicked the icon instead of the button.

Can't believe I didn't notice this before. I was just convinced it was an issue with the ajax method I was using.

Thanks again.